# mysql OR query with output

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dealer_reg_data WHERE dealercode = '$myvalue' OR sender = '$sender'";
```

if dealercode is found i want to echo message - onlydealer

if sender id found i want to show message - only mobile

if both founf i want to show message - both found

pls help how to do that, i have tried this, but it will not work for me

```
if($sender !== '' || $dealercode !== '' );{
        $reply_message = "both found";
            }
            if($sender !== '');
            {
        $reply_message = "only mobile";
            }
            if($dealercode !== '' );
            {
        $reply_message = "only dealer";
            }
```

Comment: `if($sender !== '' || $dealercode !== '' )` does not mean both found it perhaps be `if($sender !== '' && $dealercode !== '' )`

Comment: For future reference it would be useful if instead of `but it will not work for me` you posted what output/errors you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

You have an errant semi-colon and `||` should be `&&`

```
if($sender !== '' || $dealercode !== '' ); <-- HERE
                 ^^^^
                 HERE
```

so it should be:

```
if($sender !== '' && $dealercode !== '' ) {
```

`||` means `or` so only one condition needs to be true. You want `&&` which means `and` and requires both conditions to be true.

Comment: not working john, i have got only last meesssage only dealer in all cases.

Comment: That logic is correct. If it doesn't work then you need to verify your variables contain expected values. A single white space character would break your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if($sender != '' && $dealercode != '' )
    {
       $reply_message = "both found";
    }
    else if($sender != '')
    {
    $reply_message = "only mobile";
    }
   else if($dealercode != '' )
    {
    $reply_message = "only dealer";
    }
```

Try this

Comment: not working bro, i have got only last meesssage only dealer in all cases.

Comment: Try to echo $sender and $dealercode what it print??

Comment: what happen is - my query says SELECT * FROM dealer_reg_data WHERE dealercode = 'DC5432' OR sender = '8888' and in output against dealer colum i have got the value of 8888 sender (dc1111)

Comment: if $sender and $dealercode containing value then it must print `both found`